# Prolog unable to writeln elements with carriage return

Tags: prolog

I have trouble printing a list using `writeln` when it contains an element with a carriage return. Here is the code obtained from Learn Prolog Now!

```
%% Read text file into list of strings and numbers
readAll(InStream, []) :-
    at_end_of_stream(InStream), !.

readAll(InStream, [W|List]) :-
    readWordNumber(InStream, W), !,
    readAll(InStream, List).

%% read a white-space separated text or number
readWordNumber(InStream, W) :-
    get_code(InStream, Char),
    checkCharAndReadRest(Char, Chars, InStream),
    codes2NumOrWord(W, Chars).

%% Convert list of codes into a number if possible to string otherwise
codes2NumOrWord(N, Chars) :-
    atom_codes(W, Chars),
    atom_number(W, N), !.

codes2NumOrWord(W, Chars) :-
    atom_codes(W, Chars).

%% Source: Learn Prolog Now!   
checkCharAndReadRest(10, [], _) :- !.

checkCharAndReadRest(32, [], _) :- !.

checkCharAndReadRest(9, [], _) :- !.   

checkCharAndReadRest(-1, [], _) :- !.

checkCharAndReadRest(Char, [Char|Chars], InStream) :-
    get_code(InStream, NextChar),
    checkCharAndReadRest(NextChar, Chars, InStream).
```

Performing `writeln(List)` will not print the entire list.
Specifically, everything before the last carriage return in the list will be ignored and only the elements after that is printed.
Furthermore, it seems to not even write the correct thing most of the time.

For instance, something like this:

```
Source3 4 5 12 275
DEMAND 200 100 300
```

will print out something like this:

```
,DEMAND,200,100,300]
```

Naturally, I think the solution is to filter out `/r`, but I am not entirely sure how to do this. I am also interested in why this actually happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the operating-system, line endings can use a line feed (ASCII 10), a carriage return (ASCII 13), or a carriage return followed by a line feed. To account for all these cases, add the following clause (as the first one for the predicate):

```
checkCharAndReadRest(13, [], InStream) :- !,
    (   peek_code(InStream, 10) ->
        get_code(InStream, 10)
    ;   true
    ).
```

Creating a `data.txt` file using CR+LF end of lines with the content:

```
Source3 4 5 12 275
DEMAND 200 100 300
```

Gives:

```
?- open('data.txt', read, S), readAll(S, L).
S = <stream>(0x7fb55ed7d690),
L = ['Source3', 4, 5, 12, 275, 'DEMAND', 200, 100, 300].
```

Or, writing the list of read tokens using `writeln/1` as you mentioned (note that this is not a standard predicate!):

```
?- open('data.txt', read, S), readAll(S, L), writeln(L).
[Source3,4,5,12,275,DEMAND,200,100,300]
S = <stream>(0x7fb5600e9a90),
L = ['Source3', 4, 5, 12, 275, 'DEMAND', 200, 100, 300].
```

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is to simply check if `NextChar==13` and skip it.

```
checkCharAndReadRest(Char, [Char|Chars], InStream) :-
    get_code(InStream, NextChar),
    (   NextChar\=13
    ->  checkCharAndReadRest(NextChar, Chars, InStream)
    ;   get_code(InStream, NextChar2),
        checkCharAndReadRest(NextChar2, Chars, InStream)
    ).
```

I am sure someone else can do better...